# Is it possible to create N variables in C with a simple macro?

Tags: c, variables, macros

I've been studying VHDL and came in contact with the statement(not sure if this is the right word) "for generate", which allows me to instance N number of components, which lead me to think:

Is it possible to do something similar in C?

For example, you can do things like:

```
#define _VAR(x)  static int x##_data
#define STRUCT(x) {index##x, data##x, "Name " #x}
```

Probably the syntax above is wrong (I'm tired and have to wake up really early tomorrow), but you get the idea.

I am also 100% sure that this isn't possible (not from my research or what I've learned), but I still have to ask. Does a similar statement exist in C, other than creating an array:

```
#define NVARIABLES(name, x) static int ##name[x]
```

If not, do you think it would be useful (I do), could you see it in the next C revision ( C15?? :) ). Thank you for your help, and good night

Comment: What advantage does it have over an array?

Comment: There's no way to automatically create a given number of preprocessor tokens. You have to have at least one place where all tokens are listed (although once you've done this , you can add some defines and `#include` that place wherever you need to generate a lot of tokens).  Check out the Boost.Preprocessor unit to get an overview of what's possible (the C++ preprocessor is the same as the C one).

Comment: BTW the last one is `static int name[x]`  ; you do not want to paste `name` onto `int`

Comment: If you need a feature like this, you're programming wrong. You want a collection of homogeneous objects, named the same with the exception of an index? That is the *definition* of an array.

Comment: @MByD As far as I can see ... none

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thank you for your help, I'll take a look at that. And the name in the example was just an example ... sleep depravation causes some errors

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I don't need it, of course, I was just doing a pass over vhdl and remembered the for generate ... the idea got stuck in my head and I needed to know whether it was possible or not

Comment: Thank you all for your comments

Comment: I understand. Matt's comment about Boost.Preprocessor is a good one. It is crazy what you can accomplish using only the preprocessor. There are some black-magic wizards who wrote some of that stuff.

Comment: use Boost.Preprocessor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more information about this, and other things, check boost preprocessor.

Thank you everybody for you comments. You've been very helpful and pacient with a the sleep deprived version of me.

Thank you for pointing out all the information.